# RStudio, restart R without preloading .RData

Tags: r

(I have unticked "Restore .RData into workspace at startup")

RStudio has "Restart R" and "Terminate R".

"Terminate R" terminates the current R session and starts up a new one. This does not preload .RData but it is slow, takes about 10-20 seconds.

Not sure what "Restart R" is doing, it prints a message about restarting R, but it will preload all .RData. This process is quick, takes about 3-4 seconds.

Is there a quick way to restart R without preloading last session .RData in RStudio? Or is it an setup in R?

Answer (score 0):

R will always look for `.RData` unless you change the startup file.

If you want a quick start option, create a project called "Quick Start" or something and then select Tools > Project Options > Save .RData on exit > No.

Comment: Thanks. I never wanted to save anything to .RData. Where's R startup file and how can I stop it?